# How do I check that a Google Cloud service account has a particular permission programmatically?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I'm making an integration with a user-supplied GCS bucket. The user will give me a service account, and I want to verify that service account has object write permissions enabled to the bucket. I am failing to find documentation on a good way to do this. I expected there to be an easy way to check this in the GCS client library, but it doesn't seem as simple as `myBucket.CanWrite()`. What's the right way to do this? Do I need to have the bucket involved, or is there a way, given a service account json file, to just check that `storage.objects.create` exists on it?

Comment: normally if we used normal email, we got notified. I'm still wondering how to check if service account email has been invited or not....

Answer (score 1):

IAM permissions can be granted at org, folder, project and resource (e.g. GCS Bucket) level. You will need to be careful that you check correctly.

For permissions granted explicitly to the bucket:

1. Use [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) to find Cloud Storage service
2. Use [Cloud Storage API reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/) to find the method
3. Use [BucketAccessControls:get](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/bucketAccessControls/get) to retrieve a member's (e.g. a Service Account's) permission (if any).

APIs Explorer used (sometimes) has code examples but, knowing the method, you can find the Go SDK.

The documentation includes a summary for [ACLs](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/storage#hdr-ACLs) using the `List` method, but I think you'll want to use `Get` (or equivalent).

> **NOTE** I've not done this.

There doesn't appear to be a specific match to the underlying API's `Get` in the Go library.

From a [`Client`](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/storage#Client), you can use `Bucket` method with a Bucket name to get a [`BucketHandle`](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/storage#BucketHandle) and then use the `ACL` method to retrieve the bucket's ACL (which should include the Service Account's email address and role, if any).

**Or** you can use the `IAM` method to get the bucket's IAM library's (!) [`Handle`](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/iam#Handle) and then use the `Policy` method to get the resource's IAM [`Policy`](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/iam#Policy) which will include the Service Account's email address and IAM role (if any).

Comment: re: your IAM suggestion, I see that I could do `client.Bucket("myBucket").IAM().V3().TestPermissions(ctx, "storage.objects.create")`. Is that what you mean? And is that doing anything but just checking that the role is there? Why does the bucket need to be involved here?

Comment: `TestPermissions` is only for the caller. But you want to confirm an arbitrary Service Account's permissions, correct? If the permissions are specifically applied to the Bucket, you need to include the Bucket in order to determine its permissions. The challenge is that the permissions could be granted at the Project, Folder or Organization level too. I think @guillaume-blaquiere suggestion to the use IAM troubleshooter may be a better way for you to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Because of DazWilkin answer, you can check the permission at different level and it can be difficult to clearly know if an account as a permission.

For that, Google Cloud released a service: [IAM troubleshooter](https://cloud.google.com/policy-intelligence/docs/troubleshoot-access#troubleshooting_access). It's part of Policy Intelligence suite that help your to understand, analyse and troubleshoot the IAM permissions.

You have the API to call in the documentation.

Comment: Nice! I was unaware of that